# Symfony 2.1.7 and doctrine migrations bundle error

Tags: symfony, bundle, doctrine-migrations

I am following this tutorial: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html#doctrine-2-migrations

1) Installing Doctrine migrations bundle

1.1) -  adding

```
 "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
 "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

to composer.json

1.2) running

```
 php composer.phar update
```

2) adding

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
```

in AppKernel.php

3) Running

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

this should run the command and find the differences between the current entities and the database, yes?
But I get an error instead:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\symblog.dev\app\AppKernel.php on line 23
```

This is exactly the line of (2.)

Can you help me out? Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Did you get any issue running `php composer.phar update`?

Comment: no problem with composer, bundles installed ok, but when I add them to AppKernel.php hell breaks loose ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I think the bundle was renamed in the meanwhile. Try:</s> (updated question):

```php
// app/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        //...
        new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
    );
}
```

See [DoctrineMigrationsBundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) and [`DoctrineMigrationsBundle` class](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/master/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.php).

Comment: I pasted the wrong namespace/class in my Question. Now fixed. The contents of AppKernel are exaclty as you say.. will add sources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, checked the manual - no use, tried 2.1 Manual and Master branch -- also 

here is app kernel: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Gfbqp0N3) composer.json: [bastebin](http://pastebin.com/ch9nYN37)
i have both bundles installed in vendor/doctrine:
- doctrine-fixtures-bundle and doctrine-migrations-bundle, none of them works. Almost the same problem with fixtures.

Comment: @dopamine try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Generated new migration class to "D:/xampp/htdocs/symblog.dev/app/DoctrineMigrat
ions/Version20130206185826.php" from schema differences. --------- It worked like a charm!